# About life cycle methods and render in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My question is about life cycle methods in react, now i have this scenario:
Some data are fetched by ajax in ***componentDidMount*** in the parent component and then this data passed as a prop to as the child component, now we are in the child so we can implement different life cycle methods,

**componentDidMount**: can not see the true value of the prop for example logging date in it returns empty array instead of the desired array

**componentWillMount**: the same.

**componentWillReceiveProps**: the same if not use **nextProps**

**componentDidUpdate**: logging data returns the desired data passed as prop

**render**: returns the desired data

So should i always be forced to call my data in componentDidUpdate or render???, Is there a way to manage that without redux??

Comment: never in `render` ofcourse? `componentDidUpdate` and `componentDidMount` are good place for network calls.

Comment: Thank you i just need to know, why componentDidMount, ReceiveProps and willMount in the child component can not see data fetched by componentDidMount in the parent @ArupRakshit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your child's `componentWillMount` and `componentDidMount` may only be receiving an empty array (I assume this is a default) because the Child component is instantiated before the API result is returned e.g. `<Child result={result} />` as opposed to `result.length > 0 && <Child result={result} />`. Mount only happens once and then `componentDidUpdate` happens after for every prop change.

Assuming that you are just displaying the data passed down, it is perfectly acceptable to handle it in render. Otherwise if you want to perform additional side-effects then check for it's completeness in the parent component (above paragraph) at which point you should be able to see the full value in the child's `componentDidMount`. Alternatively you can perform the completeness check in the child's `componentDidUpdate` as you suggest and handle it there instead.

Comment: Thank you, but this makes react not that flexible, i find my self go and forced to write my business logic in render  and you say it is acceptable??? I tried even to take advantage of ReceiveProps by benefitting from nextProps parameter but sometimes get unexpected results

Comment: If your application is at the scale that you are concerned about business logic in UI layer, then I would suggest looking at adding on another library like Redux, MobX etc... to help you handle that. React is a view library and whilst simple business operations can be handled elegantly with setStates and the lifecycles, that isn't it's purpose. The flexibility in React comes from it's ability to integrate with other libraries for state management, business logic etc...